# How does list append behave in for loop Python 3, output not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I have tried reading similar questions on the forum, but I am unable to figure out how append works in the following situation. I believe the empty list is created wrongly?

```
combinations_run_list = []
improvement_combination_list = [['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST']]
for combinations_list in improvement_combination_list:
    holder_list = []
    for improvement in combinations_list:
        holder_list.extend([improvement])
        combinations_run_list.append(holder_list)

print(combinations_run_list)
```

**I get the output:**

```
[['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST'], ['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST'], ['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST']]
```

**While I expected following output:**

```
[['TEST'], ['TEST', 'TEST'], ['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST']]
```

What can I change in the code snippet to make the output as intended?

EDIT:
Here is the solution, a copy needs to be made:

```
combinations_run_list = []
improvement_combination_list = [['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST']]
for combinations_list in improvement_combination_list:
    holder_list = []
    for improvement in combinations_list:
        holder_list.extend([improvement])
        holder_list_tmp = holder_list.copy()
        combinations_run_list.append(holder_list_tmp)

print(combinations_run_list)
```

Comment: You are appending **a single list object** to the outer list, and keep mutating it. Appending does not create a copy, see the duplicate on how to copy a list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, reading the duplicate I understand that I need to create a copy, but where should I create the copy assignment?

Comment: For anyone who needs the answer: I solved it by adding: `holder_list_tmp = holder_list.copy()` and changing `combinations_run_list.append(holder_list)` to `combinations_run_list.append(holder_list_tmp)`